# Power series expansion of an expresion

Tags: power-series

I hope you can help me with a problem where I'm stuck. I need to expand $\frac{k!}{(1-st)^{k+1}}$ into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+k)!}{n!}(st)^n$ and I don't know where to start. Thank's you in advance.

Comment: Look at geometrical progression and its series.

Comment: Let call $x =st$. Just use the power series expansion of $1/(1-x)$ and then take $k$ times thre derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$, then the $k^{th}$ derivative is $f^{(k)}(x) = \dfrac{k!}{(1-x)^{k+1}}.$ Now, use the geometric series to get a power series formula for $f(x)$ (valid of course only for $|x| < 1$).

Comment: Thank's you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the generalized binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
  (1 + x)^\alpha
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n
\end{align*}$

Here:

$\begin{align*}
   \binom{\alpha}{n}
       &= \frac{\alpha^{\underline{n}}}{n!} \\
       &= \frac{\alpha (\alpha -1) \dotsm (\alpha - n + 1)}{n!}
\end{align*}$

If $\alpha$ is not a positive integer, the series converges only for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$.

If $\alpha$ is a negative integer, $\alpha = -k$:

$\begin{align*}
  &\frac{(-k)(-k - 1) \dotsm (-k - n + 1)}{n!} \\
     &= (-1)^n \frac{k (k + 1) \dotsm (k + n - 1)}
                              {n!} \\
     &= (-1)^n \frac{(k - 1 + n)^{\underline{n}}}
                              {n!} \\
     &= (-1)^n \binom{n + k - 1}{n}
\end{align*}$